# JUnit test case fail because of assertNotNull() but application works fine :why?

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

My `application works well`. But in my `JUnit test case fail` and it showed the lines used for `assertNotNull() method as error` lines. But when I run the application it is work well.

This is the Failure Trace:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Button not allowed to be null
at com.example.androidunittest.test.MainActivityUnitTest.testIntentTriggerViaOnClick(MainActivityUnitTest.java:39)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

And line for this error is :

```
        buttonId=com.example.androidunit.R.id.button;
        Button view=(Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
        assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null",view);
```

I am still learning JUnit and this is a tutorial that I followed. Could anyone please explain what is going on there? If there is any error in my application how can I correct it?

Any helping hand would be appreciated.

Comment: Not really familiar with android yet either but it appears that your button is null which is why the assertion is failing.  you are saying that it is not null but it probably is.  That would be my guess

Comment: yah, But my application works well. So where should I correct to avoid this failure?

Comment: You didn't show us how you obtained `view` in your test.

Comment: @dtmilano I updated the code segment.